# Python - Import module based on string then pass arguments

Tags: python

Ive searched the web and this site and cant find an answer to this problem. Im sure its right in front of me somewhere but cant find it.

I need to be able to import a module based on a string. Then execute a function within that module while passing arguments.

I can import based on the string and then execute using eval() but I know this is not the best way to handle this. I also cant seem to pass arguments that way.

My current module that would be set based on a string is named TestAction.py and lives in a folder called Tasks.
This is the content of TestAction.py:

```
def doSomething(var):
    print var
```

This is the code I am executing to import TestAction and execute.

```
module = "Tasks.TestAction"
import Tasks
mymod = __import__(module)
eval(module + ".doSomething()")
```

How can I make this code #1 not use `eval()` and #2 pass the var argument to `doSomething()`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Is the function name also variable? If not, just use your imported module:

```
mymod.doSomething('the var argument')
```

if it is, use `getattr`:

```
fun = 'doSomething'
getattr(mymod, fun)('the var argument')
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks everyone for the help. it looks like importlib combined with getattr was what I needed. For future reference here is the exact code that is working for me.

```
module = "FarmTasks.TestAction"
mymod = importlib.import_module(module)

ds = getattr(mymod, "doSomething")
ds("stuff")
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation

> it is better to use importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module.

Using this you can retrieve your module like this:

```
import importlib
TestAction = importlib.import_module("TestAction", package="Tasks")
```

After that you can simply call functions normally or by name:

```
TestAction.some_known_function(arg1, arg2)
getattr(TestAction, "some_other_function_name")(arg1, arg2)
```

I hope this answered your question, feel free to elaborate if you are still missing something.

Comment: I have a use case restricted to Python2.6. What is the disadvantage to _not_ using importlib?  Since importlib doesn’t exist for 2.6, I don’t have a choice. But I’m wondering what issues might arise? I’m assuming there must be some possible issues, else importlib wouldn’t have been created.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 2.7 or 3.1+ the easiest way to go is to use the [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) module in combination with `getattr`. Your code would look like that then:

```
import importlib

module = "Tasks.TestAction"
mymod = importlib.import_module(module)
myfunc = getattr(mymod, "doSomething")
myfunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a simple function that imports a given function, it seems to work for me:

```
def import_function(name):
    """Import a function by name: module.function or
    module.submodule.function, etc. Return the function object."""

    mod, f = name.rsplit('.', 1)
    return getattr(__import__(mod, fromlist=[f]), f)
```

You can use it as:

```
f = import_function('Tasks.TestAction.doSometing')
f()
```

or just

```
import_function('Tasks.TestAction.doSometing')()
```